# add events to full calendar and store them on mysql through servlet callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, fullcalendar

i'm new to the full-calendar jquery plugin, i have integrated the calendar in a jsp page. When the page loads, events are loaded from a MySQl database calling a servlet that generates JSON  array of retrived elements.
so far all works fine.

now i'd like to add events on calendar from client side using javascrip, i can't figure out how to make a callback function to a servlet to store the new event in the mysql DB.
i've tried to read the documentation but i'm still clueless about it.

any good advice ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind functions to the various fullcalendar event handlers. For example, you might have a Facebox overlay (or something simpler like a popup window) appear whenever a "day" is clicked.

For example, inside your `fullCalendar` definition:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

       var year = date.getFullYear();
       var month = date.getMonth();
       month++;
       var day = date.getDate();
       var hour = date.getHours();
       var minute = date.getMinutes();

       $.facebox({ajax: '/addeditevent.php?year='+year+'&month='+month+'&day='+day+'&hour='+hour+'&minute='+minute});

}
```

In this case, you would have addeditevent.php present a form for the user to add an event to your database.

Once the event is added to the database, make sure to call refetchEvents http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/ to update the calendar for the user.